# NHibernate fluent HasMany testing with PersistenceSpecification

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, testing, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table that defines a command, a command has a list of parameters and a parameter must have a command. That means a Reference in parameterMap:

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("GUID_PARAMETER").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
References(x => x.Command).Column("GUID_COMMAND").Cascade.All();
Table("MST_PARAMETER");
```

and a HasMany in command to populate the list:

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("GUID_COMMAND").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
HasMany<ParameterEntity>(x => x.ParameterList)
  .Table("MST_PARAMETER")
  .KeyColumn("GUID_PARAMETER")
  .Inverse()
  .Cascade.All();
Table("MST_COMMAND");
```

Then when trying to test that a command has a list of parameters I always get an error saying I cannot insert a parameter with a null command.

For what I've seen the proper way to achieve that is with a call like this when testing a command map

```
new PersistenceSpecification<CommandEntity>(_session)
.CheckProperty(c => c.Id, Guid.NewGuid())
.CheckList(c => c.ParameterList, FixtureUtils.GetDefaultParameterListFromCommand(), (command, parameter) => command.AddParameter(parameter))
```

Is that testeable?

Answer (score 0):

you have set `inverse=true` which means parameter is responsible for the association. Therefor you have to set the property command on the parameter:

```
.CheckList(c => c.ParameterList, FixtureUtils.GetDefaultParameterListFromCommand(), (command, parameter) => { command.AddParameter(parameter); parameter.Command = command; })
```

Update:

`.KeyColumn("GUID_PARAMETER")` should be `.KeyColumn("GUID_COMMAND")` according to the reference Declaration

Comment: Well that's what I was doing inside the `command.AddParameter(parameter)` method. Actually when I debug inside AddParameter looks like the parameter has a reference to the command and the command to the parameter. Is when nhibernate does the parameter insert that command has a NULL guid.

Comment: About the update: I guess that means that I can even skip set KeyColumn name because GUID_COMMAND. BTW I doesn't work too. I have another similar case where things seems to work a little bit more because instead an exception it says `Actual count (0) does not equal expected count (1)`

Comment: no you need to specify KeyColumn, otherwise it will default to "commandId" not "GUID_COMMAND" and insert correctly but wont find any items for the collection on loading, hence the errormessage

Comment: Yes @Firo I discover that after passing tests again as it was refering it as command_id as default key. Thanks

Comment: that even saying which parameter is responsible for the association it fails. Test starts with `INSERT INTO MST_PARAMETER...` which is good but, with a null `GUID_COMMAND` that crashes due to db constrains. @Firo